# Flutter: Using Colorfiltered with CircleAvatar results in circle image to be shown as rectangle

Tags: flutter

I am trying to apply a black and white effect on CircleAvatars, but the effect renders the image as a square. I would like it to stay circular.

```
          child: ColorFiltered(
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.grey,
              BlendMode.saturation,
            ),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.fireBasePhotoUrl),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: use [ColorFilter.matrix](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ColorFilter/ColorFilter.matrix.html) instead

Comment: Thanks that was it! If you post it as an answer, I will accept :) https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ColorFilter/ColorFilter.matrix.html

Comment: @pskink are you available for freelance? Your replies helped me a lot :) Please add some contact details for your stackoverflow accout

Comment: for freelance? not yet, but maybe in few months ;-) feel free to post a self answer with `ColorMatrix.matrix` ctor

Comment: btw using `ColorFilter.matrix` you can easily animate from color > black&wite > color using `TweenAnimationBuilder` which you cannot do  using `BlendMode.mode`